# Mixing Chinese Characters with English (Main Language) in 2019 | What is the "State of the Art"?

Tags: fonts, cjk, chinese

- I have a English document (in UTF8) and want to place in some placed Chinese translations (single words: symbols and pinyin, which is the Latin character version).
- Ideally, I want to use `pdflatex` (or `lualatex`) if that is possible.
- **What is the *start of the art* / *best practice* for including (little) Chinese text bits in a mainly English document using `pdflatex` or `lualatex`?**
- I am looking for a robust solution that may be feasible for some years.
- I am also open if you recommend *not* to do that if this a not well supported use case for LaTeX.

This is a made-up MWE :) (I just Googled the translations).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is an English text about apples 
(Chinese simplified/traditional: 
\SimplifiedChineseCharacter{苹} / \TraditionalChineseCharacter{蘋} 
(Pinyin: \Pinying{píng guǒ}))

\end{document}
```

> The question may be to broad or even stupid - this is mainly due to my inexperience in this area. I am looking for some advice and some MWEs to start with.

---

Related

- [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17611) (from 2011)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/2jyuqt/how_do_you_include_a_couple_chinese_characters_in/ (from 2015)
- https://ctan.org/pkg/cjk (from 2015)
- This user seems to be very active in the past: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674/leo-liu, but There is now activity after mid of 2017.
- [Pinyin to character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471491) (from 2018, mixing pinyin and Chinese characters, looks very cool)
- https://ctan.org/pkg/notocjksc: Famous noto fonts by Google and Adobe, see [Multiple xeCJK fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480132) and [LaTeX, CJK and Chinese gives missing font file cyberb65](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435891) for example.
- Typographical discussion about pinyin (in German): https://thetype.com/2017/08/11606/#pinyin-size

---

### Update 1: Follow-up Question

[babel: Language "pinyin"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500093)

---

### Update 2: fontspec vs. babelfont

I have noticed that David did not use fontspec in his answer - I am not an expert in fonts but I usually see fontspec when using luatex. I found the explanation in the babel manual:

> [image]

Comment: You could look through [answers by @Davislor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A61644+Chinese+babel), who seems quite knowledgeable on using Chinese with `babel` and `lualatex`. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492198/how-to-write-korean-and-chinese-within-an-german-document-with-other-european-la/492214#492214

Comment: @DavidPurton Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a `babel` implementation showing English (australian) as main language, simplified and traditional Chinese, and Pinyin.

It will compile with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Though be aware that the Chinese fonts are *huge* and it takes the LuaTeX font loader a long time and a lot of RAM to build the cache. So long, that I can't actually compile this on my computer with LuaLaTeX. (I have a 5 year old MacBook Air with 4GB RAM running Linux. My machine just runs out of resources and kills the process.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pinyin,australian]{babel}

\babelprovide[main,import,language=Default]{australian}
\babelprovide[import,language=Chinese Simplified]{chinese-simplified}
\babelprovide[import,language=Chinese Traditional]{chinese-traditional}

\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK TC}
\babelfont[chinese-traditional]{sf}{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}

\section{Roman Family}

Australian English.    

\foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{汉语。}
\foreignlanguage{chinese-traditional}{漢語。}
\foreignlanguage{pinyin}{Pīnyīn.}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\sffamily

\section{Sans Serif Family}

Australian English.

\foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{汉语。}
\foreignlanguage{chinese-traditional}{漢語。}
\foreignlanguage{pinyin}{Pīnyīn.}

\end{document}
```

I have a feeling the `language=` settings shouldn't be needed, but at least with my version of `babel`, they still are. In the future, I'd guess that this will work without explicitly specifying the `language`.

## XeLaTeX output

Notice the difference in how the Chinese full stop is rendered in simplified and traditional Chinese.

[image: MWE ouptput]

Comment: That's a great answer. I will try to compile it on my computer. I need to install noto fonts first.

Comment: Do you have experience with the \usepackage{xpinyin} https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471491? Would you recommend using it?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, sorry, I haven't used `xpinyin`. Looks like an interesting package though.

Comment: Hi, I can compile it now. **(1)** I do get the warning `Package babel Warning: Unknown language 'pinyi'` - do you know where I can get `pinyin.ldf`? **(2)** I had to  copy the fonts into `[...] AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\opentype\google\noto` - do you know why? I also installed them normally as system fonts but that wasn't enough apparently. Please tell me, if I should ask a new question rather than using the comment function.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I don't know about fonts and Macs. I have the fonts installed as system fonts in the usual way on my Linux machine. For `pinyin.ldf`, I think it's in the `cjk` package. (Makre sure you spelt it right: it's `pinyin`, not `pinyi` like your error message.)

Answer (score 7):

With `pdflatex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\newcommand{\chinese}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}#1\end{CJK}}

\begin{document}

This is an English text about apples
(Chinese simplified/traditional: \chinese{苹}/\chinese{蘋},
Pinyin: píng guǒ)

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `xelatex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Songti SC} % use a font you have that covers Chinese

\begin{document}

This is an English text about apples
(Chinese simplified/traditional: 苹/蘋, 
Pinyin: píng guǒ)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Thank you very much! Would a LuaTeX solution be almost identical to the XeLaTeX solution?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'm not sure: `xeCJK` exploits character classes, which are not supported in LuaTeX.

Comment: I don't think this adequately deals with differences between simplified and traditional Chinese. You need to use different font settings (or different fonts). And I notice `babel` has hyphenation patterns for pinyin (though I don't know how significant this is).

Comment: The character 内 doesn't show up on the page using the pdflatex solution but the sample ones do.